# How to compute the queue id if I can compute the RSS hash with Software implementation(rte_softrss)?

Tags: dpdk

My NIC is Intel I210 and driver is e1000. DPDK version is latest 19.11.5. I'm trying to do following work:

1. compute RSS hash by software (it should be save with mbuf->hash.rss);
2. infer the queue id based on the computed hash(it should be save with the real received queue id)

My question is how to infer the queue id based on the hash.

Comment: marking this question as `required clarity` because of missing information such as `1. DPDK version, 2. NIC firmware 3. NIC ASIC details`. Note: it is not SW (that is PMD) which does RSS hash, but the HW ASIC which does the same. Please update the question with the details.

Comment: Question title and content is also confusing. In title you are asking for `how to compute RSS hash by SW`. But in driver `e1000` uses `E1000_READ_REG` and `E1000_WRITE_REG` to update HW for RSS reta. So it looks like you want to implement SW RSS but issue you are facing packet is already received on NIC port-queue. So once again please update your question .

Comment: can you please share the correct update with right question concerning to either software or hardware.

Comment: @VipinVarghese , I know you are expert about DPDK. I have another question about RSS filter. Expect your answer!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64966952/whats-the-rss-filter-function

Comment: thank you for your kind words, sure I can look at your other question.

Comment: please consider the following there are 2 HASH function 1. Symmetric (Toeplitz) and 2. asymmetric (normal hash).. DPDK `rte_softrss` computes symmetric hash and you can simply `hash % number of the queue`. In case of generic hash on ASIC one needs to check in the datasheet (for x710 the hash computation is defined). for understanding the computation.  With these information then you can compare `rte_softrss` vs rss value that came in mbuf.

Answer (score 1):

For any physical NIC in DPDK the RSS value is calculated by ASIC before injecting the packets into final queue destination. This information is available once the Poll Mode Driver extract from `NIC descriptors` and puts in `mbuf->hash`. Each NIC and vendor will have their custom gate logic implementing the same, which can be found in the data sheet.

In case of intel i210, one can find in the datasheet `v3.6` figure `7-6` while the hash logic pseudo-code is explained as

```
ComputeHash(input[], N)
For hash-input input[] of length N bytes (8N bits) and a random secret key K of 320 bits
Result = 0;
For each bit b in input[] {
if (b == 1) then Result ^= (left-most 32 bits of K);
shift K left 1 bit position;
}
return Result;
```

Hence it is not the DPDK PMD which determines the end RSS but the ASIC logic

Answer (score 0):

In I210 datasheet 7.1.2.10 chapter, It answers how to compute the queue id based on the hash.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/design/products-and-solutions/networking-and-io/ethernet-controller-i210-i211/technical-library.html?grouping=EMT_Content%20Type&sort=title:asc

[image]