# What's the RSS filter function?

Tags: dpdk

I'm looking some doc about RSS filter funciton. NIC is Intel I210 and driver is e1000. I found some functions about RSS filter. Like:

```
eth_igb_start => igb_filter_restore => igb_rss_filter_restore => igb_config_rss_filter
```

igb_config_rss_filter will write RSS configure(rss reta, rss key and rss protocol) to NIC register.

My question is what's the different between igb_config_rss_filter and igb_rss_configure? Can you share some doc about DPDK filter?

Thanks

Comment: is your question `what is the difference with DPDK generic RSS setup?` and `RSS reta update, get, set? in ethdev library`?

Comment: I have tried to explain in detail latest comment of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925261/how-to-compute-the-queue-id-if-i-can-compute-the-rss-hash-with-software-implemen?noredirect=1#comment114857152_64925261

Comment: my question is what's the different between igb_config_rss_filter and igb_rss_configure? They all will write the RSS configure to NIC register.

Comment: can you please update the question `1. with the above comment, 2.  the results or logs if any`.

Answer (score 0):

igb_config_rss_filter is used by the flow filter function. For example, if you create a flow filter rule, this function will be invoked.

igb_rss_configure is used to config RSS function.